# Displaying two different types of variables in one label string

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, cclabelttf

I am trying to make a `CCLabelTTF` display a string and an integer together. Like this:

> Your score is 0.

I've tried a few things but I usually get the warning `Data argument not used by format string`, and the label doesn't output the correct statements.

I am just trying to figure out the format in which to put these in and searching Google hasn't provided much, as I'm not really sure what exactly to search.

I've tried

> label.string = (@"%@", @"hi", @"%d", investmentsPurchased);

but obviously that isn't correct. How would I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I assume this is ObjC and not Swift.) Try something like this:

```
label.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hi %d", investmentsPurchased];
```

You use a single format string, which contains static text and replacement tokens (like `%d`) for any replacement variables. Then follows the list of values to substitute in. You can use multiple variables like:

```
label.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"number %d and a string %@", someInteger, someString];
```

Answer (score 1):

use `NSString newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello %@", investmentsPurchased];`

in short: use `stringWithFormat`